# How to "erase" some of my sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I've done quite a bit of sculpting on an object (way too much to start over) but I don't like what I did in a certain region. I'm past the point of undo. Is there any way to reset, or erase, the sculpting on only that region?

*Edit*: I realize that I can continue sculpting such that it looks more like its original state.

I'm specifically asking if Blender stores the original state of the mesh at a per-vertex level, and if you can revert a set of vertices to that state - sort of a "reset these to the point before you hit Subdivide, then reapply the current level of subdivision to them" operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is impossible. Blender does not store a record of the previous location of individual vertices. Once you have sculpted an area, it edits the original mesh.

**There are many workarounds though.**

The most effective (and in a way, easy) method would be to select the area you would like to undo (in edit mode) and delete it. You can then remake it, or go back to a previous save/version you have created, and copy back that section. For this method to be effective you need to save a version of your project before you begin sculpting.

However, if you are going to begin a new model from scratch, I would suggest one of these methods.

First, you could create a gray-scale texture, and paint on this, using it as a displacement for the original mesh. You then "sculpt" in texture paint mode.
The main downfall to this is that it cannot auto-update. You need to switch to edit mode and back to see the changes take effect.

### **The best method**

You can model your object, then duplicate it (make sure it is unwrapped). Now sculpt on the duplicate. when you are done (or want to undo something), you can bake the normal map for the sculpt onto the original. (there are lots of tutorials on baking normal maps.) Now use this map in a displacement modifier (on the original mesh) with "direction" set to "RGB to XYZ".

[image]

With either of these methods, to remove a portion, use a vertex group to "mask out" the results.

(Using these methods you will need a subsurf modifier to enable the displacement, or to subdivide your original model for more control.)

### Here are some more "corrective" options

---

Use the *"smooth"* tool.

[image]

You can also hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> which generally does the "opposite" of whichever tool you are using.

Otherwise you can use undo.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to continue sculpting correctively. I'm asking for a way to clear the sculpting work in that region altogether - as if I never did it - but only in that region, as I want to keep the work I've done elsewhere on the mesh.

Comment: Once you have sculpted an area, it edits the original mesh. It does not keep a record of what is sculpts, and what is edit mode. So that is technically impossible. If I were you I'd just select the area you would like to undo and delete it. You can then remake it, or go back to a previous save/version you have created, and copy back that section. Then just fill in the gaps and connect it.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't imagine it keeps a record of every stroke, but I was hoping it would keep a record of the original state at a per-vertex level. So you'd be able to choose a series of vertices and tell it to revert those to the original state. If you post an answer to the effect of "it's not possible because..." I'll accept it.

Comment: Okay. I'm not *positive* it's not possible (I'm not that smart :P) but I'm pretty sure. You could probably develop an addon for it, so it saves it in some type of file, but I wouldn't know how to do that either. You may want to get some more professional help and opinion on this, but you may not find that on Blender.Stackexchange (although there are many great people on here). For now, I'll update my answer, and you can accept if you want, or wait for more help.

Comment: I think is something that would be very simple to implement.  It appears the multires modifier is just saving a per vertex translation, so reverting to the original state seems very possible.  With an erase brush to simply remove all translation.  I have some vertices that are giving me trouble, as I moved them in the base mesh, and now they are spiking way out from the base mesh.  Finding these vertices is hard, as they return to base position in edit mode, and because they're one little spike, you have to get just the right angle for the brush to affect them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer I'm looking for, but I thought I'd post it as an alternative. In this case the offending region happened to be unconnected - a satchel on the hip of a character - and not seamless with the rest of the mesh.

1. I selected those vertices and separated it to a new object.
2. I deleted the new object's Multires modifier, and then added a new one with default settings.
3. I joined the new mesh to the original one.

The result was that it retained the existing sculpt information on the original parts, and subdivided the newly joined region wholesale (as opposed to iteratively, which is what happens when you click the the Multires' Subdivide button repeatedly). Step 2 above turned out to be important, because without a Multires modifier on the object I was joining, it cleared all the existing sculpt information on the original. No idea why.

So in the specific case where you can separate part of a mesh and then rejoin it, you can "clear" the sculpt information from the part you rejoin while keeping the sculpting on the original, as long as there's a "placeholder" Multires modifier on the part you're adding.

Comment: The modifiers are taken from the object which is active when joining. If you selected original mesh last the joined mesh would have original mod. Beware also that with object which have "modifier with default settings" selected last you can erase the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I couldn't find an answer to something similar anyway. Then I realized you can use the F Clay brush and a dynotopography (dynotopo) of say 30 px so that the section is simplified to the point that you can either erase it or repexilize with a lower dynotopo of say 5 px.This way you don't get holes and you can perfectly remove large pieces of "arms" quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the mask to tool to mask the region then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert  the selection then use the *Scrape Tool* with a Max shape curve, *Strength* to 1, few stroke and you are done.